# Are there any free Windows programs to get a live view for a Nikon D700 in tethered capture mode?

Tags: nikon, live-view, tethering, windows, studio

Are there any free Windows programs to get a live view for a Nikon D700 in tethered capture mode? I'm trying to hook it up to my computer monitor for some studio shooting.

Comment: I can't speak for Nikon but Canons all come with the EOS Utility software that includes tethering support. Does Nikon not provide something similar?

Comment: @Mark Whitaker - Nikon charges for it. However, a quick Google search comes up with a bunch of free options so that seems like a good place for the OP to start.

Comment: I realize this question is 3 years old but there is an Android app that allows you to control a D700 using a USB "on the go" cable. The app is free and USB OTG cables only cost ~$5 USD. It works nicely with a tablet although a tablet is still not as large as a PC monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No free software exists to do this on Nikon cameras in Windows.**

The only two options I know of that allow live view are [Nikon Camera Control Pro 2](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/25366/Camera-Control-Pro-2.html) and [NKRemote by Breeze Systems](http://www.breezesys.com/NKRemote/index.htm). They both run between $150-200USD. If you do not want to spend any money, free options exist but they do not offer Live view as far as I have found.

**If you are really in a bind, and need a free option, you can download free trials of either Camera Control Pro 2 or NKRemote and try each out for 30 days.**

I would try out **[DIYPhotobits.com Camera Control](http://www.diyphotobits.com/download-diyphotobitscom-camera-control/)**. They have quite a few iterations of the software, and it has been around for a while. It gives you similar functionality to the Nikon Camera Control software, but for free.

I have not used the software first hand, but you can tell by the comments on the download page that people are very happy with it.
On the [compatibility chart](http://www.diyphotobits.com/2008/12/10/what-works-and-doesnt-work/) it does have the D700 listed as compatible.

It offers control of the camera, and time lapse functions as well. You can shoot RAW or JPEG in it as well.

It does not look like live view is offered, which is unfortunate. But I am not sure of this so I would download it since it is free and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Nikon SDK C# wrapper library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nikoncswrapper/).

According to the site you can:

- Control your Nikon DSLR via USB
- Capture JPEG and RAW images directly to system memory
- Receive 'Live View' images
- Record video
- Query and change camera settings (exposure, aperture, ISO, etc.)

I'm not entirely sure which Nikon cameras are supported, but I briefly tried it with my D7000 and it worked well for something that's free. I recommend you try it to see if it will work for you.

You will need to compile the source code to get it going; you can use [Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop).

Answer (score 1):

I just exhausted all my Google-Fu on this issue for another camera, and came up with the same answers.  I so wish I'd found this page first.

digiCamControl (freeware) has [the D700 listed as compatible](http://digicamcontrol.com/cameras) with Live View, but does not record video.  You could possibly do remote shooting/control.

In the non-free realm in addition to marc and dpollitt's suggestions, Smart Shooter supports the D700.  (link redacted, I do not have the rep for it)

In a pinch, you could try [ControMyNikon](http://www.controlmynikon.com/download)  (commercial product download page).  This lists the D700 as supported also and offers a 14-day full feature trial.  That might be enough to complete a project.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with, nor a representative of the linked companies/products.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up Alzo Digital, CT.

They are very helpful in providing me with answers as well as getting my camera to shoot wirelessly to the computer.

Comment: Have you a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom has tethered capture, but now it is only available through monthly/ yearly subscription. $10 a month for the latest lightroom and Photoshop. At $600 for just PS (when you could buy it), it's a good deal, and you always have the latest version of them both. 
Both of them are very handy, PS is dang near indispensable.